# Setting adview in place of title

Tags: android, admob, ads, adview

I have 2 questions.

1. Which is the best source to implement ads on your android app? AdMob? or is there a better one?
2. How can I place the adview in place of the title at the top? please see attached picture. [image]

Comment: 1. `best source to implement ads` ? any tutorial or best Ad provider having good `ecpm` 2. You can use Native Ads to show ad on particular view.

Comment: 1. Best source to implement ads